# λ and function javascript

Tags: javascript

is there any way to map the λ key to the function keyword?
so that these work:

```
var rFalse = λ() {
  return false;
}

(λ(){
  var str = "i'm in a closure";
}());

window.onload = λ() {
  alert('window loaded');
}
```

I know that they are attempting to put a shortened function keyword in ecmascript v6, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do it now.

Comment: Wouldn't it be tedious to type that character? What about `func`?

Comment: I use autohotkey, a program for remapping keyboard commands so right ctrl+l is λ

Comment: Still, I think `let`, `def`, or `func` make more sense.

Comment: I feel it's just my personal preference, Javcascript does use first class Lamda functions (inherited from Scheme/Lisp) so it does kindof make sense; I also like the way it looks `λ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, just not natively. You'd have to look into implementing or using an existing [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

A good example could be [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org), which includes an *Extras* script for [running on client-side via](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#scripts):

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
```

Their contents are converted to and reinserted into the document as JavaScript by:

```
<script src="extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
```

However, keep in mind that client-side DSLs risk drastically increasing load times and ruining the user experience -- CoffeeScript is primarily server-side for a reason.

Comment: I am looking into this and see plenty of promise; may be using my own custom `type="application/λ-script"` soon enough;

Comment: Coffeescript files can be compiled to pure readable JavaScript files. So you can write in coffeescript and just use the generated JavaScript client-side. No slow down at all.

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript does not offer aliasing of keywords, so it is not possible make the syntax you're trying to use valid.

Comment: thanks I have been trying to find a way, but i guess I'll just have to hope that they confirm it in ECMA 6

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't think so, since `function` is a keyword... You'll have hard time passing your program through the parser.

Comment: Well, if you do that, that's almost trivial.

Comment: yeah the only benefit of that is for your own personal use as a custom server-side javascript interpretor

Comment: @Rixius, @Kobi - Incidentally, I have been working on my own for the past month. Mainly as a fun learning experience. I have mostly everything working, I just need to read through all those dry algorithms for the built in objects and implement them. :(

Comment: I would love to modify my own implementation of V8 and use it for myself on a server-side, but I don't know c++ and don't have enough free time to learn it for a simple pet project.